# How to pass a set of json data in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, json, function, parameter-passing

I have a data set as below:

> data = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6},{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9}';

I am trying to make a function with the data set as its parameter, but the parameter wouldn't be read. Here is what I did:

> function add(data) { alert(data); } add(data);

I only get [object Object],[object Object] ...
What's the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: try to console instead of alert, you will get your expected result

Comment: There's no problem. You are passing a list of objects and you're receiving it.

Comment: alert tries to convert data into string, and object.toString() is "[object Object]", so try extracting the value from data and then do alert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JSON string is wrong. It should be actually:

```
var data = '[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6},{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9}]';
```

After that, you need to convert the *JSON* String into *JSON* object using the code below:

```
JSON.parse(d) /* d is the parameter of the method 'add()'  */
```

The `alert` will give you `[object Object]` output, as the variable `data` is itself the object. So if you want to see the whole `json` data, you need to `console.log` as:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(d));
```

Watch the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/j8np1o5c/).

Comment: The alert give you [object Object] but you can also stringify the JSON to show it through an alert.
`alert(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(d)));`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your data value is incorrect. Since it has 3 objects it has to be in an array. So, your data should be

```
data = '[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6},{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9}]';
```

Then you need to use JSON.parse function to parse the string data into javascript object and then pass the object.

```
function add(data)
{ 
   alert(data);
   alert(data[0].a); //access 1ts objects a value
} 
var data = JSON.parse(data);
add(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should pass the function an object parameter and you can store the object in an array:

```
var data = []; //array
function add(d) {
 data.push(d); //add passed item to array
 console.dir(data); //this will print the whole object
}

add({"a":1,"b":2,"c":3});
```

`console.dir()` will make you print the properties within the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

The data needs to have a JSON structure however.

So in your case that would be:

```
var data = [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6},{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9}]
add(JSON.stringify(data))

[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6},{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9}] //output of JSON.Stringify()
```

Answer (score 0):

am also getting same issue few hours later and I fixed it using JSON.parse(data)..Like bellow coding

```
var data = '[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6},{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9}]';
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
obj.forEach(myFunction);
function myFunction(item, index) {
     var eachid = item.id;
     console.log("Item-id", eachid);//you will get id 
     add(eachid);
}
```

you are directly pass the data .so only you get the [objcet Object]...if you using JSON.parse(data) ,You will get the id of each item